# How A block-level element as heading can be centered using text-align?

Tags: html, css

isn't text-align property  center inline and inline-block element and text inside block level elements but how come it can center a block level element inside another block level element(like h1 in div)??
isn't the h1 tag already takes the whole width so we have to center it with the other ways like margin:auto way or using positioning, how text-align work on it??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that both `<div>` and `<h1>` are [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and thus occupy the full width of their parent by default. However, [`text-align`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/) aligns the **content** of a block-level element, not the text. That is to say, `text-align` affects **all** `inline` or `inline-block` elements in that container.

Considering `<h1>` allows [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), the `<h1>` element interprets the text as a pseudo-element of the phrasing content type, is able to assign a `width` to it, and thus is able to center it:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```